# Regex for moving based on last 4 digit combinations in a file

Tags: bash, shell, find, pipe

I have files which are labelled in the following manner, and need to move them according to 0000 - 0010 (base the last 4 digits. What is the regex for this?
I have tried this regex but I don't get anything. As someone who isn't an expert on regex any help would be appreciated.

```
find ./ -regextype egrep -regex '.*file([0-9]\+-[0-9]\+-[0-9])\+.flac'
```

I get no output from my regex, but would like to copy only 0000 to 0010 to a new location

```
1241-137614-0000.flac
1241-137614-0001.flac
1241-137614-0002.flac
1241-137614-0003.flac
1241-137614-0004.flac
1241-137614-0005.flac
1241-137614-0006.flac
1241-137614-0007.flac
1241-137614-0008.flac
1241-137614-0009.flac
1241-137614-0010.flac
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest with `bash` version >= 4.0:

```
mv 1241-137614-{0000..0010}.flac <destination_dir>
```

If a source file does not exist, you will get an error message from `mv`.

Comment: Hi, Cyrus thanks for your answer. May I ask what does the .. siignify and any other example that you could provide maybe?

Comment: `..` is part of the syntax of Brace Expansion. See: [Brace Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html)

Answer (score 1):

For moving files I agree with @Cyrus. If you still need the regex for scripting purposes, this works:

```
echo "1241-137614-0001.flac" | grep -E -o ".{0,4}.flac" | tr -d '.flac'
```

although there may be a better way to remove the extension.